# SSIS - Unable to load DLL 'clrcompression.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, variables, dll, ssis

I need to compress a data folder in SSIS.
For that, I use a Script task which runs this script :

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            try
            {
                string zipPath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::sFolderCompressed"].Value;
                string startPath = (string)Dts.Variables["User::sFolderSource"].Value;


                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                // Log the exception
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

The 2 variables I have set up:

[image]

Executing the Script Task step gives me the following error:

> {System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'clrcompression.dll':
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x8007007E)    at Interop.inflateInit2_(Byte* stream, Int32
> windowBits, Byte* version, Int32 stream_size)    at
> System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(String archiveFileName,
> ZipArchiveMode mode, Encoding entryNameEncoding)    at
> System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.DoCreateFromDirectory(String
> sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName, Nullable`1
> compressionLevel, Boolean includeBaseDirectory, Encoding
> entryNameEncoding)    at
> System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String
> sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName)    at
> ST_19ce97c462f844559ec30884173f5a28.ScriptMain.Main() in
> c:\Users\SQL\AppData\Local\Temp\3\Vsta\46892b1db29f45f2a8e1fb8c5d37a542\ScriptMain.cs:line
> 104}

Error message is pretty clear that I am missing a 'clrcompression.dll' file somewhere.
Can I just download this DLL? and where do I copy it to?

**UPDATE**

Added 'Execute Process Task' and set  the following:

```
Executable : 'powershell.exe'  
Arguments : -nologo -noprofile
    -command "Compress-Archive -Path E:\Flat Files\IT\StockAge\Stock Age Difference\MAINCHECKK807Babbage\BabbageStockAgeingPartno.csv
    -DestinationPath E:\Flat Files\IT\StockAge\Stock Age Difference\MAINCHECKK807Babbage\BabbageStockAgeingPartno.zip"
```

But getting error:

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "powershell.exe" "-nologo
> -noprofile -command "Compress-Archive -Path E:\Flat Files\IT\StockAge\Stock Age
> Difference\MAINCHECKK807Babbage\BabbageStockAgeingPartno.csv
> -DestinationPath E:\Flat Files\IT\StockAge\Stock Age Difference\MAINCHECKK807Babbage\BabbageStockAgeingPartno.zip"" at "",
> The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

**UPDATE 2**

Executing the script in PowerShell gives me the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tasks only have access to the DLL's that have been registered in your [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) or have been [manually loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac) within the script. If you want to use a script task you'll need to load the DLL for the script to be able to run

Alternatively for basic zip functionality you can use a command line tools and call it from an execute process task. If you have the latest windows server running with all the .net frameworks installed you can try the PowerShell method, else use the 7zip method

**PowerShell Zip Method**

Set up the the execute task so that it calls PowerShell and passes your zip instruction in the arguments

[image: Execute Process Task]

```
Executable = 'powershell.exe'
Arguments = Powershell -nologo -noprofile -command 'Compress-Archive -Path \"C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.txt\" -DestinationPath \"C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.zip\"'
```

*Edit 1*

If your paths have spaces then you need to escape them with backslash and double quotes

Your Arguments should be

```
-nologo -noprofile -command 'Compress-Archive -Path \"E:\Flat Files\IT\StockAge\Stock Age Difference\MAINCHECKK807Babbage\BabbageStockAgeingPartno.csv\" -DestinationPath \"E:\Flat Files\IT\StockAge\Stock Age Difference\MAINCHECKK807Babbage\BabbageStockAgeingPartno.zip\"'
```

*Edit 2*

To debug the command try running it in PowerShell as below, see if there are any additional information

[image: Running the command from PowerShell]

[image: ZipFile]

**7Zip Method**

Install 7zip 64bit on all the servers this package will be running on

You need to ensure that the install directory matches between servers or else ssis will not find the executable when deployed

```
Executable = C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
Arguments = a -r "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.zip" "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.txt"
```

[image: 7zip]

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have updated my question with the error after attempting "Execute Process Task" route. Please advise.

Comment: @PKirby your paths have spaces in them so you'll need to add quotes to them, will update my answer

Comment: Thanks, I added the suggested Argument but even though the Task executes successfully, the zip file doesnt get created. No errors so not sure how to step through the issue. Any advise?

Comment: If you try and run the command in PowerShell does it give you any additional information? See updated screenshot on running the command from PowerShell.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @Ockert, I've added the PowerShell result to my post.

Comment: @PKirby It looks like you are running PowerShell 4 which doesn't support zipping, If possible, upgrade to PowerShell 5 if you would like to use that solution. Otherwise you could try installing 7zip and calling it from an execute task to zip your file, for exampe 7z.exe a -r "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.zip" "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.txt"

Comment: Thanks @Ockert , I've upgraded the PowerShell version to 5.1 but now getting a "The underlying compression routine could not be loaded correctly" error.  Any ideas? Or should I just try the 7zip route?

Comment: @PKirby, I think try the 7zip route, it should not have any other dependencies on windows, it should just work

Comment: Will definitely try that! So using the 'Execute Process Task' , what goes under 'Executable'? and Argument will be "z.exe a -r "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.zip" "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.txt""

Comment: I'll update my answer with the 7zip solution, Executable needs to be the the 7zip command line tool, there will be a browse button on that field, browse to the installed folder and select 7z.exe and the arguments should be: a -r "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.zip" "C:\SO\Test Folder\Test.txt"

Answer (score 0):

**clrcompression.dll**
is a part of .NET Framework.

I think you need to check .NET Framework installation on your machine.